# How to Access "New Products" in cart-preview

Tags: bigcommerce

In my cornerstone theme I can access "new products" on the homepage by using [yaml front-matter](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/using-yaml-front-matter) like this

```
---
products:
    new:
---
```

But that wont work for template files. So im wondering if i can do something like this.

```
utils.api.products.new( { template: 'cart-upsells' }, (err, response) => {
    if (err) { return false; }
    $upsells.html(response);
});
```

This doesnt work either though cause i dont think `utils.api.products.new` exists.

I am also open to using the BC-api if its the only way — say i did return a bunch of json from the api could i template it out using handlebars some how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New products are globally available, so you should be able to access them on the cart preview modal without an API call.

Could you try adding the new products front matter to your **cart.html** page? That should invoke the object so you can access new products on **preview.html** using `{{products.new}}`

```
---
products:
    new:
        limit:
---
```

**Edit:**
To access the new product object in the mini-cart preview in the header (cart-preview.html), you can use the {{inject}} and {{jsContext}} helpers to expose the new products object and do things with it in your code. For example, added to base.html:

```
{{inject 'newProducts' products.new}}



<script>
    var jsContext = JSON.parse({{jsContext}});
    console.log(jsContext.newProducts);
</script>
```

You can use this method to call jsContext.newProducts in the mini-cart preview. You will want to make sure that all of your page types (category, product, page, brand) invoke front matter for new products for the object to show up.

**Edit #2:** You can add 'New Products' as config in your cart-preview.js options array and that should give cart-preview.html access to {{products.new}}. Your options array should look like this in cart-preview.js:

```
$cart.on('click', event => {
        const options = {
            template: 'common/cart-preview',
            config: {
                products: {
                    new: {
                        limit: 3,
                    },
                },
            },
        };
```

Then, you can use handlebars in cart-preview.html to print out the properties:

```
{{#each products.new}}
{{name}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: i cannot use frontmatter in the components. I am using it on many places and can do it on the cart page also but not in the header where the preview-cart lives

Comment: That's true, but invoking the front matter on the cart.html page should allow you to use new products in a cart component. I tested this and confirmed--could you let me know if you see something different when you try?

Comment: When you say cart preview, do you mean the modal that pops up after you add a product to cart, or the modal that drops down from the cart icon in the main nav?

Comment: Yes this is not on the cart page. Its the mini cart in the header

Comment: That would be be a bit trickier :). I'll edit my answer to address it

Comment: oh this is interesting; where can i read more about jsContext? right now `{{jsContext}}` is logging `undefined`... I put the script tags right in the header html and im testing it on a page that has products.new invoked with front-matter

Comment: actually `console.log(jsContext);` is an empty obj `{}` and `console.log(jsContext.newProducts);` is `undefined`.

Comment: Did you place both {{inject}} and {{jsContext}} in base.html or did you put it in the header? In base.html, place the {{inject}} statement in the <head> beneath the others that are already there, and the <script> that parses {{jsContext}} into JSON and console logs it beneath the footer component. Here's a link to some additional documentation on {{jsContext}}: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#inject

Comment: Awesome. I am able to see the products in the console.log... Now How can i use handlebars to template out that data?

Comment: example: `{{#each products.new}} <h3>{{name}}</h3> {{/each}}`

Comment: I think you'd need to use Javascript rather than handlebars to template it out, because the inject helper delivers the object to the browser and handlebars compiles/interprets server side. *But* I think I've got a better way to do this. I'll update my answer with more info

Comment: Wow Edit 3 is magic. Where can i read more about how that worked?

Comment: We don't have any documentation on this yet, but I'll work with our team to get something written up :)

Comment: Can i use some version of this to access specific products or categories in places that i wouldnt normally

Comment: In the example above, new products is returned in the context of the getContents ajax call--it wouldn't be available to anything else. We're basically specifying that we need additional info with this ajax call. To make an object available to an entire page, it would need to be part of the front matter for that page.

Comment: Does this include product options?